# how do i attach files without userlogin

Tags: visualforce, email, attachment

I have this visualforce emailtemplate where i can send the attachments on quotes as a link but the receiver needs to be logged in. How do i manage this whitout a login. Or can i send the body of the attachment with the mail. Here is my code: `

```
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
    <html>
        <body>
        <p>Dear {!recipient.name},</p>
        <p>Quote</p>
        <center>
         <p>..   ..</p>
        </center>
    <br/>
    <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Attachments}">
      <a href="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, cx.Id)}" target="_blank" styleClass="btn">Download {!cx.Name}</a>
    <br/>
    </apex:repeat>
        </body>
    </html>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
```

`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not possible without writing an custom controller with apex class.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include more detail about what you did. As written, this post does not add much value to the community.